# Normalizing a table, from one to the other

Tags: sql, mysql

I'm trying to normalize a mysql database....

I currently have a table that contains 11 columns for "categories". The first column is a user_id and the other 10 are category_id_1 - category_id_10. Some rows may only contain a category_id up to category_id_1 and the rest might be NULL.

I then have a table that has 2 columns, user_id and category_id...

What is the best way to transfer all of the data into separate rows in table 2 without adding a row for columns that are NULL in table 1?

thanks!

Comment: Why does it have to be the best way? Can't it just be the quickest and easiest way? Isn't this is only something you will do once?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create a single query to do all the work, it just takes a bit of copy and pasting, and adjusting the column name:

```
INSERT INTO table2
SELECT * FROM (
    SELECT user_id, category_id_1 AS category_id FROM table1
    UNION ALL
    SELECT user_id, category_id_2 FROM table1
    UNION ALL
    SELECT user_id, category_id_3 FROM table1
) AS T
WHERE category_id IS NOT NULL;
```

Since you only have to do this 10 times, and you can throw the code away when you are finished, I would think that this is the easiest way.

Answer (score 0):

One table for users:

```
users(id, name, username, etc)
```

One for categories:

```
categories(id, category_name)
```

One to link the two, including any extra information you might want on that join.

```
categories_users(user_id, category_id)

-- or with extra information --

categories_users(user_id, category_id, date_created, notes)
```

To transfer the data across to the link table would be a case of writing a series of SQL INSERT statements. There's probably some awesome way to do it in one go, but since there's only 11 categories, just copy-and-paste IMO:

```
INSERT INTO categories_users
SELECT user_id, 1
FROM old_categories
WHERE category_1 IS NOT NULL
```